# https to http redirect not working in nginx configuration using rewrite

Tags: django, python-2.7, redirect, nginx

To distribute load and implement security in our application we have taken elastic Load Balancer from amazon and SSL is configured on it.Now the redirection from http to https is not working in nginx configuration on server or instances which is attached on ELB.
Here is following nginx configuration:-

```
 server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name new.example.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;
        location / {
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
                proxy_connect_timeout 90;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
              }
}
```

Firstly the server is not supporting https URLs then I add some proxy settings in configuration but now issue is that redirection is not working i have used the following commands in ngnix configuration to redirect http to https :-

```
#version 1   
    server{
      return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

#version 2   
    server {
     rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
    }
```

Application deployed on server is build using django framework.

Comment: you are listening (w/ above config) on port _80_, but https requests go to port _443_; might that be the issue?

Comment: no,request is coming on port 80 in both the case.

Answer (score 0):

When I've done something similar, then I've set up the ELB HTTPS to redirect to HTTP port 80 on the node.  I've then set up a second nginx vhost on the node, e.g. on port 81, which directs to return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri; and set up the ELB http listener to redirect to that port (where $server_name obviously points to the domain CNAME of the ELB)

I then make sure that the instances behind the ELB cannot be accessed from outside my VPC using security groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django, you can use it to do the redirection, this give a lot of flexibilty like enabling HTTPS redirects only on production server or choose which urls to redirect from:

```
# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')

# Redirect to HTTPS in production
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = not DEBUG

# Disable redirection on this urls
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = [
    '^legacy/api/',
]
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately It is not working for me,If you can give me some other solution,it would be grateful.